# PL/SQL developer import dump

Tags: oracle, dump, plsqldeveloper, tablespace

I have a dump file which includes two tables. Now I need to import this dump file. I was instructed to create two tablespaces beforehands.Now how do I import this dump file to these tablespaces. I'm using PL/SQL developer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot import a dump file from PL/SQL developer. Instead, you have to do it from the command line. Furthermore, you need access to the file system of the database server since you have to put the dump file in a directory directly accessible by Oracle.

The tool to import the dump file is called *impdp* (in earlier version, it was *imp*).

My experience is that you need information how the dump file was created so you can use the correct import mode:

- Is it a dump of the full database or just a single user/schema?
- Does it include the table schema or just the table data?
- What's the schema/user name if a single schema was exported?
- etc.

You'll find more information about *impdp* on this [PSOUG web page](http://psoug.org/reference/datapump.html).

Comment: Just to complete the picture: *impdp* and *imp* are two completely different tools and the dump files are not compatible. *impdp* needs the dump file on the server whereas *imp* is a client side program and the dump file is read on the client side.

Comment: To add to horse with no name's point, imp can work on the server too.

Comment: Thanx buddy. Your answer and the link you provided will help me a lot

Answer (score 4):

You CAN import a dump file from PL/SQL developer.
Tools -> Import Tables... -> (at the botton of the popup screen) select the file and click in "Import".