# Import with pl/sql developer

Tags: import, plsqldeveloper

I have an sql file that contains user schema with all objects(tables, packages) which I get by export user objects in pl/sql developer.
Now I need to import it to my database. How I can do it with pl/sql developer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PL/SQL developer import dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160097/pl-sql-developer-import-dump)

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches come to mind:

1. Open the file with SQL Developer and Execute it (select the appropriate connection if prompted)
2. Open a connection, and in the SQL Worksheet:

   @"C:\Path\To\My Schema\import.sql"

Then Execute as a statement.

Comment: SQL Developer as nothing to do with PL/SQL Developer.