# Importing Oracle dmp file into AWS RDS

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services

We're trying to import a dmp file that is on our local machine onto an external database on AWS RDS. We have tried using the Toad GUI tool and get the error:

IMP-00038: Could not convert to environment character set's handle

The dmp file is encoded with ANSI encoding which I'm assuming is what Toad should be expecting.

From what we have read we need to use imp rather than impdp ([PL/SQL developer import dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160097/pl-sql-developer-import-dump)) since we have the file locally.

There doesn't seem to be an option on Oracle SQL Develop to import from a dmp file.

We have tried using IMPDP with the command:

IMPDP usr/pass@connection directory='our_local_dir' dumpfile='file.dmp' logfile='log.txt'

We got the error:

UDI-00014: invalid value for parameter, 'directory'

I'm just looking for any advice on how to import this dmp file and which tools we need to use.

Comment: Was it created with `exp` or `expdp`? If the latter you can't then import wth `imp`, they are different formats. Have you looked at [Amazon's instructions for importing data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html)?

Comment: Got this working from the amazon instructions, although they aren't very clear on how to import from a local dmp file

Comment: Is not posible. Check this thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=415864. So Is there no alternative?